# Neither stable or unstable equilibrium

Tags: dynamical-systems

I found a non-linear dynamical system which has a line of equilibrium points at $y=0$; when linearizing and evaluating at those points I find that Jacobian matrix is J=$\begin{bmatrix}0 &1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ on the line;
 what can I say about the kind of equilibrium?

Answer (score 1):

This indicates that there are no stable and no unstable dynamics around the critical point. You may want to look at the [center manifold](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_manifold).

Comment: If you look at the characteristic equation of the matrix you get $\lambda ^2 = 0$.  So you have 2 poles at origin which would mean the system is unstable around operating point. Am I right ?

Comment: It's not asymptotically stable indeed. But you'd have to look at the center manifold to see if it is lyapunov stable.

Comment: So i can say that all those points are neither stable or instable, and to study stability of the origin i have to look at the center manifold?

Comment: You cannot conclude anything about the points _before_ looking at the center manifold. They may be either stable or unstable :)

Comment: Ok! So for example, in a system like this $\begin{cases}\dot{x}=(a-1)xy\\ \dot{y}=-y^2\end{cases}$I study center manifold and i get that points along $y=0$ are unstable for every value of a; correct? Center manifold should be $y=(a-1)x$ and the respective motion $\dot{x}=(a-1)^2x^2$ ; right?